# Optimal solution to finding all points within a certain distance

Tags: algorithm

I have to find the nearest points within a particular distance for every point. For every 3d-point provided (labeled 1...n) I have to show all the nearest neighbors within a certain distance `r`.

I solved it, but my algorithm is O(n^2) and I'm not sure how to improve it.

I tried thinking about sorting all the points but I would still need to iterate over all `x` elements that are within distance `r`, making it a O(nx log n) algorithm, which isn't any better for large `x`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Point {
    double x, y, z;
    double square(double v) {
        return v * v;
    }
    double operator-(Point const& rhs) const {
        return sqrt( square(rhs.x - x) + square(rhs.y - y) + square(rhs.z - z) );
    }
};

int main() {
    float r;
    int n;
    std::vector<Point> points;
    std::ifstream s("file2.txt");
    std::cin.rdbuf(s.rdbuf());
    assert(s.is_open());
    assert(std::cin >> r >> n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double x, y, z;
        assert(std::cin >> x >> y >> z);
        points.push_back({x, y, z});
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(n, vector<int>());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << i << ": ";
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (points[i] - points[j] <= r) {
                adj[i].push_back(j);
                adj[j].push_back(i);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < adj[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << adj[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This is the output, which is correct:

```
0: 1 2 3 8 
1: 0 4 6 8 
2: 0 4 5 8 
3: 0 5 6 8 
4: 1 2 7 8 
5: 2 3 7 8 
6: 1 3 7 8 
7: 4 5 6 8 
8: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I don't want the answer but a nudge in the right direction. Or is this the best I can do given I have to print all the points out?

Comment: Nudge: Consider only 1 dimension. Sort the data. Now search, O(log n) difficulty.  Next try 2 dimensions. Make a quad tree.  Search that tree.  Now go for 3-D and make an [oct-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For the 1d variant, I sort it and have to get the upper and lower bound of the range, but I still have to print the entire range for every point, which was the concern I had before. Wouldn't that still make it no better than the naive algorithm?

Comment: This is called the [Fixed-radius near neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors) problem. You can do better than O(n^2), depending on output size: for example, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925772195000097) based on Delaunay triangulation gives an `O(n log n + Output-Size)` algorithm.

Comment: If the range of the coordinates has an upper bound and the distance r a lower bound, you can sort the points into a fixed number of buckets. The buckets can be accessed in O(1) instead of O(log n) access time of sorted points.

Comment: @Sebastian The constraint is that x,y, and z is between -10^5 and 10^5.

Comment: The size of the distance r relative to 2*10^5 is important. I saw this idea is listed in the Wikipedia article, kcsquared linked, under the section "rounding and hashing" and the article about "integer lattice". Depending on the density of the points and the available memory hashing or an array with a linked list of points makes more sense, if you go this direction.